# Класс массива с++

Tags: c++, массивы, классы

Нужно сделать сортировку, увеличить массив на 1, добавить значение в конец  (PushBack), удалить элемент с конца (PopBack) и реверс массива...

Помогите хотя бы с PushBack, остальное как-то сам домучаю?

````
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
 
class MyArray {
    
    int* data; // ядро класса, указатель на дин. массив
    int size; // размер массива, вручную менять нельзя.
 
public:
    
    MyArray() :MyArray(0)
    { }
 
    MyArray(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        this->data = new int[size];
    }
    MyArray(const MyArray& other) : MyArray(other.size)
    {
        /*
        this->size = other.size;
        this->data = new int[size];
        */
 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 
            this->data[i] = other.data[i];
        }
    }
    ~MyArray()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
 
    int GetSize() {
        return this->size;
    }
 
    void Print() {
        cout << "Array " << this <<
            ". Size: " << size << endl;
 
        cout << "[  ";
 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << data[i] << "  ";
        }
 
        cout << "]" << endl << endl;
    }
 
    void SetByIndex(int index, int value) {
 
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            cout << "ERROR! Out of array size (SetByIndex)" << endl;
            return; 
        }
        else {
            data[index] = value;
        }
    }
    int GetByIndex(int index) {
 
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            cout << "ERROR! Out of array size (GetByIndex)" << endl;
            return 0; // в случае вылезания за массив, возвращаем 0.
        }
        else {
            return data[index];
        }
    }
 
    
    void Sort() {
        // сортирует массив
    }
    void FillRand() {
        cout << "[ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = rand() % 50;
            cout << data[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout << " ]";
    }
    void pushBack(int value ) {
        size++;
        cout << "( ";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 
            temp[i] = data[i];      
        }
        cout << " )";
        int* temp = new int[size];
        cout << "[ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp[i] = data[i];
            cout << temp[i]<<" ";
        }
        temp[size - 1] = value;
        cout << " ]";
         
        delete[] data;
        data = temp;
        temp = 0;
    }
};
void main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    MyArray arr(4);
    arr.pushBack(5);
    arr.FillRand();
    
    cout << endl;
    arr.SetByIndex(0, 228);
    arr.SetByIndex(1, 1337);
    arr.SetByIndex(2, 555);
    arr.SetByIndex(3, 785);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 
        cout << arr.GetByIndex(i) << endl;
    }
    
    arr.Print();
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Операция `PushBack` сразу показывает недостаток текущего дизайна: каждое добавление элемента требует заново выделить массив и скопировать его целиком. Это работает медленно.

Нужно добавить поле `capacity`, которое будет хранить текущую вместимость массива - сколько выделено памяти. Поле `size` остаётся. Оно хранит число элементов в массиве. `size` <= `capacity`.

Так как переделки затрагивают конструкторы, то они переписаны с использованием списков инициализации.

За изменение вместимости отвечает метод `ensure_capacity`, который при нехватке места увеличивает вместимость сразу в два раза. Долго объяснять, но такое скачкообразное выделение нужно что массив можно было быстро заполнять одними операциями `PushBack`.

```
class MyArray {
public:
    
    MyArray(int size = 0) : capacity(size), size(size), data(new int[capacity])
    {}

    MyArray(const MyArray& other) : capacity(other.size), size(other.size), data(copy(other.size, other.data))
    {}

    void PushBack(int v)
    {
        ensure_capacity(size + 1);
        data[size++] = v;
    }

    ~MyArray()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

private:
    static int* copy(int n, int data[/* n */]) {
        int* copy = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            copy[i] = data[i];
        }
        return copy;
    }
    
    void ensure_capacity(int n) {
        if (capacity < n) {
            int* copy = new int[2 * n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                copy[i] = data[i];
            }

            delete [] data;
            data = copy;
            capacity = 2 * n;
        }
    }

    int capacity; // вместимость массива, вручную менять нельзя.
    int size;     // размер массива, вручную менять нельзя.
    int* data;    // ядро класса, указатель на дин. массив
};
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать как инициализировать вывод?

Comment: Не понял вопрос.

Comment: Как вывести пушбек и т.д

Comment: Непонятно. Вывести пушбек? Пушбек - операция, её не выводят. Ею меняют состояние массива.

Comment: Имел в виду массив с пушбеком

Comment: Пишите метод, который вернёт размер массива. Затем доступ к элементу. У вас там они есть для старого кода. Для нового разницы не будет.